# image 404 in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am making a catalog of film directors for an introduction to django exercise and im trying to load the images from my database to my template but is not working.

All my steps:

I added an imagefield to the directors model class, which I have then filled in from the admin version.

Then in my view I have made a request to collect a list of all directors like so:

`directors = Directors.objects.all()`

and then I have returned it with render.

In the template I have done this

```
{%for director in directors%}
 
<img src="{{director.director_image.url}}" alt="{{director.first_name}}">

{% endfor %}
```

And everything is fine except that the images are not loaded, the alt with the names of the directors are ok :D (an advance). I get the feeling that somehow I have to define the url of the images??? because from the browser console it get the url of the images properly but it gives a 404.

im really on my first days using django so I guess im missing something with how the media urls works.

hope someone can help me. tysm <3

What I tried?
I haven't tried anything else since I'm very new to django. I have searched in google how images are treated and I have read that a root is necessary for your media? I simply added the imagefield to my model and in the admin view I uploaded it but I have not done anything else.

What I want?
I want to show the images of all the directors in my template

Comment: can you share views and models

Comment: @ManojTolagekar sure here boths

views: https://pastebin.com/Ea8w4Fjg
models: https://pastebin.com/zzgEuJaB  (i just pasted the film directors model)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You `mispelled` directors `spelling` in template.

change this:

```
{%for director in directors%} #According to view, you mispelled directors spelling here
 
<img src="{{director.director_image.url}}" alt="{{director.first_name}}">

{% endfor %}
```

To this:

```
{%for director in directores%} #Here you did mistake
 
<img src="{{director.director_image.url}}" alt="{{director.first_name}}">

{% endfor %}
```

Now your problem is solved.